# Android studio object is null or not null?

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm experiencing following strange behaviour in android studio ...

An object is null in the source code but if I try to check it in the watch list it is not null and all properties are readable.

provider and database are objects implementing interfaces.

[image]

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
If I switch the accesibility of the database object to private and then extend the interface with getDatabase() and setDatabase() the databse object being returned is NOT NULL.

Comment: Does it bother? What happens on runtime (in case you can check)? Maybe it's just a little bug in Android Studio.

Comment: without the if operator it crashes because the database member is null

Comment: Then it's a bug in Android Studio.

Answer (score -3):

If `this.provider` is null, `this.provider.database` is automatically also null.

Only check for one of these.

Or use the `&&` operator.

Comment: this.provider is not null only the database member and only in the sourcecode, if I preview the provider object the database member is not null ...

Comment: If an object is null, it is nothing, so you can't call anything on it, right?